# Reporting Services 0X80070005(E_ACCESSDENIED) System.Web.RegularExpressions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

recently in the server that i work with, the security team made a Hardening, after that the reporting services gives this error whenever someone (including administrators) try to access de site:
[Description of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfFTK.png)

It's important to mention that the service run under a Domain account, for a week after the hardening the server runs smoothly but for some reason now shows this error.

We searched a lot and give the permissions to the Domain user and network service under de directories C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET , C:\Program files\Microsoft SQL Server\XXX\Reporting Services\Report server

But nothing seams to work. The error keeps the same. We also tried adding this users to the group "Distibuited COM Users" as it was in an answer in another question here.

I will appreciate the help because i am running out of ideas of what access i should grant.

The server has windows server 2012 and reporting services 2014.

Comment: Are you running the reports from a webpage reportviewer? If so take a look in the web config of the report viewer project and see if it's uasing a username and password. Like so <identity impersonate="true" userName="blah" password="blah">. Delete the username and password.

Comment: @ Snowlockk thanks for the suggestion, but i already do that and problem persist .